# how to use a vector from another class

Tags: c++, qt, class

I have a class named `variable` which has

```
string name;
double value;
```

and I have another class named `mainwindow` (by the way it is qt application.)
in main window I have a vector 
`vector<variable> vect`
I want a class which `push_back` variable objects with using vect which is under main window 
I wrote this but it gave me error

```
class add_variable
{
private:
  variable var;
  MainWindow &vectholder;
public:
  void push_back(var.getname(),var.getvalue());
};
```

errors

```
error: 'var' is not a type
error: expected ',' or '...' before '.' token
```

also I want to reach these variables which is pushed into vector
I want to call them within another class

Comment: Where is class `variable` declared? And what about `push_back`?

Comment: I suggest you take your time, and slowly but surely learn C++ from [a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), because there are here more errors (or bad designs) to makes a simple specific question that suits the Q&A format of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Anyway, I can still comment here: it makes no sense to use a class `add_variable`, containing the variable you want to add in `vectholder.vect`. What you should do instead is to add a *method* to `MainWindow`, that looks like: `MainWindow::push_back(variable var) { vect.push_back(var); }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `push_back` function

```
void push_back(var.getname(),var.getvalue());
```

is not right. You should put argument list in the parenthesis. That's why the compiler is expecting a `type`. What you can do is

```
void push_back() {
  vectholder.vect.push_back(var);
}
```

Comment: then how can I get these pushed variables within another class for example if I declare mainwindow a; in another class it will be new object and it wouldnt have pushed variables

Comment: @CihadYildiz If I understand you correctly, you need a way to pass in a `variable`. You can define a public method `setVar` that takes a `variable` argument and set `var` to that argument.

Comment: I didnt understand exactly but when I create an object of mainwindow there will be new object so it will have new vector inside it am I wrong or do I misunderstand these class and class object things

Comment: @CihadYildiz Yes you'll have an empty vector and you need to define how to add things to this vector.

Comment: I understand adding into vector but how can I get things which is added into vector

Comment: @CihadYildiz You can define `get` methods in your class for example `variable getVar(int index) { return vectholder[index]; }` and call this method to retrieve what's in your vector holder.

Comment: @Yang: Note that in this case, `vectholder` is *not* a vector, but contains one. so you should edit your answer and use `vectholder.vect`  instead (if I understood the OP question well).